# Async call non-static methods from NETCore Windows Service

Tags: asynchronous, .net-core, static, windows-services

I've been converting a windows service to NETCore and followed a simple guide to get my intended results before finishing it up.
After it was done, I decided I should convert the static methods so that I could implement unit tests more easily, but that led me to a situation where I have no idea what's going on. This Windows Service supposedly operates based on a timer, where it'll call every couple of seconds, a method from a different project to perform varios asyncronous calls. Though there was a problem, it seems that after removing the static property from all methods, I started getting an error, saying I'd need an object reference for the non-static method.
This is what I have so far

```
        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (timer == null)
        {
            timer = new System.Threading.Timer( (e) => OnElapsedTime(), null,TimeSpan.Zero,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15) ); 
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async void OnElapsedTime()
    {
       await Logic.OnElapsedTime(Client,handler);
    }
```

The method I'm attempting to call is

```
public class Logic
{

    public async Task<object> OnElapsedTime(HttpClient Client, HttpClientHandler handler)
    { (...)
```

I can't seem to be able to perform this call without getting an error, I've tried to instantiate Logic before, and there'd be no errors until I got to the publishing part where it prompted. Any help on figuring out what's going on and if it is even possible to achieve what I'm looking for without referring to static methods?

This is the guide I've used to set up my Windows Service in netCore by the way:
[Guide](https://medium.com/@tocalai/create-windows-service-using-net-core-console-application-dc2f278bbe42)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution to my issue in the meantime, by using the Invoke method instead. I also refactored the Logic method to not take any parameters in the meantime, though that was completely unrelated to the issue I was having.

```
typeof(Logic).GetMethod("OnElapsedTime").Invoke(new Logic(), null)
```